# pandas pivot and join in two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, pivot

I have two dataFrames :

```
df1
   mag   cat
0  101   A1
1  256   A2  
2  760   A2
3  888   A3  
...

df2
   A1    A2    A3    ...
0  E50R  AZ33  REZ3 
1  T605  YYU6  YHG5
2  IR50  P0O9  BF53
3  NaN   YY9I  NaN
```

And I would like to create a final DataFrame which looks like :

```
df
   101   256   760   888  ...
0  E50R  AZ33  AZ33  REZ3
1  T605  YYU6  YYU6  YHG5
2  IR50  P0O9  P0O9  BF53
3  NaN   YY9I  YY9I  NaN
```

I tried something with pivot, but it doesn't seem to do the job
Could you help me ?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is the guide to posting good questions on SO. You should show what you've tried so far.

Comment: I think transposing one of the tables and joining them might work.

Comment: i think Josh is right, but you should probably start by cleaning your data. it might be worth checking out something like this https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i10

Comment: It's already a "minimal" example. What should I've done to minimalize it more ? And what do you mean by "cleaning your data" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a combination of `GroupBy`, `numpy.repeat`, `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain

# map cat to list of mag
s = df1.groupby('cat')['mag'].apply(list)

# calculate indices for columns, including repeats
cols_idx = np.repeat(range(len(df2.columns)), s.map(len))

# apply indexing
res = df2.iloc[:, cols_idx]

# rename columns
res.columns = list(chain.from_iterable(df2.columns.map(s.get)))

print(res)

    101   256   760   888
0  E50R  AZ33  AZ33  REZ3
1  T605  YYU6  YYU6  YHG5
2  IR50  P0O9  P0O9  BF53
3   NaN  YY9I  YY9I   NaN
```

**Performance benchmarking**

Some good and different solutions here, so you may be interested in performance. Wen's `reindex` solution is the clear winner.

```
%timeit wen(df1, df2)   # 632 µs per loop
%timeit jpp(df1, df2)   # 2.55 ms per loop
%timeit scb(df1, df2)   # 7.98 ms per loop
%timeit abhi(df1, df2)  # 4.52 ms per loop
```

Code:

```
def jpp(df1, df2):
    s = df1.groupby('cat')['mag'].apply(list)
    cols_idx = np.repeat(range(len(df2.columns)), s.map(len))
    res = df2.iloc[:, cols_idx]
    res.columns = list(chain.from_iterable(df2.columns.map(s.get)))    
    return res

def scb(df1, df2):
    df_out = (df2.stack().reset_index()
                 .merge(df1, left_on='level_1', right_on='cat')[['level_0','mag',0]])
    return df_out.pivot('level_0','mag',0).reset_index(drop=True)    

def abhi(df1, df2):
    return df2.T.merge(df1, left_index=True, right_on='cat').drop('cat', axis=1).set_index('mag').T

def wen(df1, df2):
    newdf=df2.reindex(columns=df1.cat)
    newdf.columns=df1.mag
    return newdf
```

Answer (score 8):

IIUC `reindex` +re-name

```
newdf=df2.reindex(columns=df1.cat)
newdf.columns=df1.mag
newdf
Out[519]: 
mag   101   256   760   888
0    E50R  AZ33  AZ33  REZ3
1    T605  YYU6  YYU6  YHG5
2    IR50  P0O9  P0O9  BF53
3     NaN  YY9I  YY9I   NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way you can do it using `stack`, `merge`, and `pivot`:

```
df_out = (df2.stack().reset_index()
             .merge(df1, left_on='level_1', right_on='cat')[['level_0','mag',0]])

df_out.pivot('level_0','mag',0).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
mag   101   256   760   888
0    E50R  AZ33  AZ33  REZ3
1    T605  YYU6  YYU6  YHG5
2    IR50  P0O9  P0O9  BF53
3     NaN  YY9I  YY9I   NaN
```

Comment: Nice 2-liner +1 :). But I think `stack` makes this slow (I always wonder why they can't make it faster).

Comment: I aggree. you can probably use melt there instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by transpose and merge and then set column 'mag' as index. Then again transposing it.

```
df2_transposed = df2.T
res = df2_transposed.merge(df1,how = "left",left_index=True,right_on='cat')
del res['cat']
res.set_index('mag', inplace=True)
res.T

mag 101      256    760     888
0   E50R    AZ33    AZ33    REZ3
1   T605    YYU6    YYU6    YHG5
2   IR50    P0O9    P0O9    BF53
3           YY9I    YY9I
```

Comment: Nice.  I like this solution too.  FYI, you can chain that in to a one-liner if you would like `df2.T.merge(df1, left_index=True, right_on='cat').drop('cat', axis=1).set_index('mag').T`

Answer (score 2):

This is slower than Wen's solution, but I think conceptually simpler:

```
newdf = df2[df1.cat]
newdf.columns = df1.mag
```

The first line says "the ith column of `newdf` should be the column of `df2` that corresponds to ith element of `df1.cat`". The second line says "The columns of `newdf` should be named according to `df1.mag`"